# Call tooltip function from page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tooltip

I created a function that acts like a tooltip. When a user hovers over the "help" label, a balloon message is meant to appear providing the user with details. The trouble I'm having is how to call the function on page load.

```
    Protected Sub AddHelpToolTip(ByVal getHelp As String, ByVal toolTipText As String)
    ' Add tooltip
    Dim scriptName As String = "tooltipScript" + getHelp
    If (Not Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me.GetType(), scriptName)) Then
        Dim myScript As New StringBuilder()
        myScript.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>")
        myScript.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {")
        myScript.AppendLine("$('[id$=" + getHelp + "]').qtip({")
        myScript.AppendLine("content: {text: '" + toolTipText + "'}, ")
        myScript.AppendLine("show: { solo:true },")
        myScript.AppendLine("hide: { when: 'mouseleave', fixed: true, delay: 500 },")
        myScript.AppendLine("position: {")
        myScript.AppendLine("corner: {")
        myScript.AppendLine("target:         'middleRight',")
        myScript.AppendLine("tooltip:        'middleLeft'")
        myScript.AppendLine("},")
        myScript.AppendLine("adjust: { screen: true }")
        myScript.AppendLine("}")
        myScript.AppendLine("});")
        myScript.AppendLine("});")
        myScript.AppendLine("</script>")
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), scriptName, myScript.ToString(), False)
    End If
```

Comment: When you are creating a Javascript function why you want to call it from Page Load? Anyways it will run on the client and you should do all these stuffs like tooltip at client only.

Answer (score 0):

You must utilize an AJAX method.

1- Write your function in Javascript and put it into page.

2- Add a ScriptManager to page.

3- Utilize the ScriptManager to call that function

I recommend you serach the ScriptManager information to see how call Javascript functions via ASP.NET code behind.